# Not able to install mysqlclient in Django project

Tags: django

Not able to install mysqlclient in Django project. While running pip giving error as "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 Is Required Error".

Tried downloading Microsoft C++ Build Tools

Comment: `pip install --upgrade setuptools` try this first

Comment: You need to install setuptools first.

Answer (score 0):

First try upgrading `setuptools` package through:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then try to install again.

If still the issue persists then use the binary-only option for pip.

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```